# Azure AD B2C Authentication with OWIN in ASP.NET: Works on localhost but not on server

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, azure-ad-b2c, owin

I am integrating Azure AD B2C authentication into my ASP.NET application using the OWIN middleware. I've set up the OWIN middleware for handling the B2C authentication as follows:

```cs
app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions 
{
    CookieManager = new SystemWebChunkingCookieManager()
});
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    MetadataAddress = String.Format(Globals.WellKnownMetadata, Globals.Tenant, Globals.DefaultPolicy),
    ClientId = Globals.ClientId,
    RedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
    PostLogoutRedirectUri = Globals.RedirectUri,
    UseTokenLifetime = true,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        ValidateIssuer = false
    },
    Scope = "openid profile offline_access",
    CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager(),
});
```

Here's the observed behavior:

Localhost:

When I run the application on localhost and click on "Sign In", the Azure AD B2C sign-in/sign-up flow gets triggered correctly. After entering credentials and authenticating, it redirects back to the application, and the authentication cookie is correctly stored in the browser. The application recognizes the user as logged in.

Production Server:

After deploying the application to the server, I click on "Sign In" and it prompts me for credentials as expected. However, post-authentication, it redirects me back to the home page without setting any authentication cookie in the browser. Due to the absence of the authentication cookie, the application doesn't recognize the user as logged in.
On trying to "Sign In" again, it directly redirects me to the homepage, still without any cookie.
I've ensured that the reply Urls are set correctly in the app and App Registrations in B2C, but it remains unresolved. Could someone guide me on how to troubleshoot and fix this behavior on the server?

Comment: Could you please share the Redirect URI screenshot ?